# Kubernetes session affinity after timeout doesn't maintain session for same client

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have exposed service as NodePort in Kubernetes and applied session affinity to that service. When the client connects to the service for the first time the session affinity comes into action and maintain the session for a client but after timeoutSeconds when the client connects again with service session affinity doesn't come into action which leads to inappropriate behaviour. I am using minikube to configure the cluster on AWS ec2 instance. k8s version is Major:"1", Minor:"18". Actually I have exposed service web-svc on node port and client connect to this service through AWS public IP e.g AWS-instance-ip:NodePort. The client first connects on UDP port sending single packet for authorization, once authorized the pod say POD-A insert some iptables rules to allow particular client, after authorization client immediately establish a TCP connection with service but the problem is this request is sent to another pod say POD-B as I have replica=3 and on POD-B, iptables rules are not present for a particular client.

When I delete my Deployment and Service altogether like `kubectl delete -f my-deployment.yaml` and then create it again through `kubectl apply -f my-deployment.yaml` i get the expected behaviour both UDP and TCP connection are going to the same pod but after sessionAffinity mentioned timeout when client connect again the UDP and TCP connection doesn't go to the same pod.

Kube-proxy mode is [IPVS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs)

Service Snippet:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: web-svc
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      selector:
        app: web-app
      externalTrafficPolicy: Local
      sessionAffinity: "ClientIP"
      sessionAffinityConfig:
        clientIP: 
          timeoutSeconds: 240
    ports:
  - port: 30573
    nodePort: 30573
    name: tcp-30573
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 30375
    nodePort: 30375
    name: udp-30375
    protocol: UDP
```

kube-proxy logs:
`sudo kubectl logs kube-proxy-njwxl -n kube-system I0820 10:22:03.591026       1 node.go:136] Successfully retrieved node IP: 172.31.27.53 I0820 10:22:03.591320       1 server_others.go:259] Using ipvs Proxier. W0820 10:22:03.591341       1 server_others.go:436] detect-local-mode set to ClusterCIDR, but no cluster CIDR defined I0820 10:22:03.591346       1 server_others.go:447] detect-local-mode: ClusterCIDR , defaulting to no-op detect-local W0820 10:22:03.591667       1 proxier.go:429] IPVS scheduler not specified, use rr by default I0820 10:22:03.591989       1 server.go:583] Version: v1.18.3 I0820 10:22:03.592440       1 conntrack.go:52] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 131072 I0820 10:22:03.596529       1 config.go:133] Starting endpoints config controller I0820 10:22:03.596556       1 shared_informer.go:223] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoints config I0820 10:22:03.600578       1 config.go:315] Starting service config controller I0820 10:22:03.600600       1 shared_informer.go:223] Waiting for caches to sync for service config I0820 10:22:03.697978       1 shared_informer.go:230] Caches are synced for endpoints config  I0820 10:22:03.700844       1 shared_informer.go:230] Caches are synced for service config`

Comment: Please provide more information, inputs: k8s version, how did you configure your cluster, and provide some commands did you use and the results for this specific issue: `session affinity doesn't come into action which leads to inappropriate behaviour`

Comment: @Hanx Description updated.

Comment: If I have understood correctly you are running minikube on AWS ec2 instance?

Comment: @Hanx yes, i am running minikube on AWS ec2 instance.

Comment: So you are trying to setup minikube + ipvs+ sessionAffinity. What is your minikube version and did you check `kube-proxy` logs?

Comment: @Hanx minikube version: v1.12.0. Yes, I have deployed minikube + ipvs+ sessionAffinity. kube-proxy logs are mentioned above.

Comment: the last question: `but after sessionAffinity mentioned timeout when client connect again the UDP and TCP connection doesn't go to the same pod` After it happens what is observed behavior after this event?

Comment: @Hanx After this, the client can not log in and thus can not use assigned services.

Comment: We have service definition but how this can be recreated? Do we have some public/opensource reproducible backend for this scenario?

Comment: @Hanx Sorry, At the current moment, we don't have any such thing.